# Write text to a file in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a simple output to a file but I'm getting the wrong output. This is my code:

```
Map<Integer,List<Client>> hashMapClients = new HashMap<>();
hashMapClients = clients.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Client::getDay));

Map<Integer,List<Transaction>> hasMapTransactions = new HashMap<>();
hasMapTransactions = transactions.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Transaction::getDay));

//DAYS
String data;
for (Integer key: hashMapClients.keySet()) {
    data = key + " | ";
    for (int i = 0; i <hashMapClients.get(key).size();i++) {
        data += hashMapClients.get(key).get(i).getType() + " | " + hashMapClients.get(key).get(i).getAmountOfClients() + ", ";
        writer.println(data);
    }
}
```

I get this output

> 1 | Individual | 0,
>
> 1 | Individual | 0, Corporation | 0,
>
> 2 | Individual | 0,
>
> 2 | Individual | 0, Corporation | 0,

But it should be, also it should not end with , if it's the last one.

> 1 | Individual | 0, Corporation | 0
>   2 | Individual | 0, Corporation
>   | 0

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: You're iterating through each line and appending `,` to it. Your `for` loop doesn't care whether it's the last line, so you'll need to handle this case separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you only want to write `data` to the output in the *outer* loop, not the *inner* loop.  The latter of which is just for *building* the `data` value to write.  Something like this:

```
String data;
for (Integer key: hashMapClients.keySet()) {
    // initialize the value
    data = key + " | ";

    // build the value
    for (int i = 0; i <hashMapClients.get(key).size();i++) {
        data += hashMapClients.get(key).get(i).getType() + " | " + hashMapClients.get(key).get(i).getAmountOfClients() + ", ";
    }

    // write the value
    writer.println(data);
}
```

**Edit:** Thanks for pointing out that the last character also still needs to be removed.  Without more error checking, that *could* be as simple as:

```
data = data.substring(0, data.length() - 1);
```

You can add error checking as your logic requires, perhaps confirming that the last character is indeed a comma or confirming that the inner loop executes at least once, etc.

Comment: Still add the removal of the last comma on the line. ;)

Comment: thanks man you are smart. Can you tell me how I remove the comma if it's the last key?

Comment: Good catch from both of you, I didn't notice that part.  @dsada: I've updated the answer.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that concatenation is not very efficient if we are using it in loop to create longer strings. Preferred way would be using StringBuilder, or if there should be delimiter (and optionally prefix/suffix) StringJoiner. This would also handle comma ad the end.

Comment: it's ok. it will be max 100 or so

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you are calling `println` after every `Client`, rather than waiting until the whole list is built. Then, to fix the problem with the trailing comma, you can use a [joining collector.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-)

```
Map<Integer,List<Client>> clientsByDay = clients.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Client::getDay));
/* Iterate over key-value pairs */
for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Client>> e : clientsByDay) {
    /* Print the key */
    writer.print(e.getKey());
    /* Print a separator */
    writer.print(" | ");
    /* Print the value */
    writer.println(e.getValue().stream()
      /* Convert each Client to a String in the desired format */
      .map(c -> c.getType() + " | " + c.getAmountOfClients())
      /* Join the clients together in a comma-separated list */
      .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
}
```

Comment: that looks ***pro level*** i have no idea what is that

Comment: @dsada But you used `Collectors.groupingBy(Client::getDay)`; this is much the same, perhaps a bit simpler!